# Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have asp.net web api 3.1 application where I have a controller like,

```
 public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    public WeatherForecastController(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
    }
    
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
```

Now in `Startup` class I have registered service like below,

```
  services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();
        services
            .AddHttpClient<WeatherForecastController>((serviceProvider, client) =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5002");
            });
```

In app startup I am getting below error. What could be the issue?

```
 InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate 'WebApplication4.Features.Weather.WeatherForecastController'.
```

Comment: why negative vote guys?

Comment: i don't understand the negative votes either.    maybe show more of your ioc code (full method of your services.Add code.

Comment: services.AddHttpClient<WeatherForecastController>()           can you try just doing that first .. to see if you get null?         (maybe add a null check on the constructor for kicks as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you inject HttpClient like that, you're trying to create a Typed Client.

In your case, you should use HttpClientFactory directly or use a Named Client.

Look at this link that has the 3 ways to inject HttpClient:
https://www.talkingdotnet.com/3-ways-to-use-httpclientfactory-in-asp-net-core-2-1/

(examples are for net core 2.1, but work the same in 3.1)

Comment: Great link, but probably worth integrating the highlights in your answer here in case that link dies (it's also a suggested practice).

Comment: Unfortunately the link does seem dead now :(

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error with Azure Function

There are two modes in which you can run your .NET class library functions: either in the same process as the Functions host runtime (in-process) or in an isolated worker process. In case of isolated-worker Program.cs file is the entry point for the app.

I was trying to inject HttpClient with Startup.cs but then got error "Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient' while attempting to activate azure function"

For dependency injection at isolated-worker Azure Function use Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Learn more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#dependency-injection)